# Woocoommerce, get variation name from variation id

Tags: woocommerce

I've used the following to get the variation id of a product in shopping cart.

```
    $cartdetails = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();


foreach($cartdetails as $cart_items) {
$variation_id = $cart_items['variation_id']; //get variation id of product in cart
}
```

I've checked the array and the variation name isn't a value.  How do i get the variation name from the variation id?

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `get_formatted_name()` method on a product object. I believe that the object might be included in the `$cart_items` array, but I am not 100% sure. If not, then you can get the product and use that.

```
$variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
$variation->get_formatted_name();
```

Comment: Worked for me Wc 2.6x

Comment: This is a good solution for getting the whole variation product name, something like 'T-Shirt Red Large (#123)'.

Comment: Works but also displays the variation id like this Variable Product - Size Attribute - large (#15)

Answer (score 5):

You can get the raw value corresponding to the variation id  by calling the `$variation->get_variation_attributes();` method.

```
$variation = wc_get_product($item['variation_id']);
$variation_attributes = $variation->get_variation_attributes();
```

the return array `$variation_attributes` will contain the corresponding variation *name* or *value* you need (for me it was the size of a shoe)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Once you have the variation slug, you call `wc_attribute_label()`.

Assuming you have access to `$product`, or thereabouts:

```
    foreach ($product->get_available_variations() as $variation) {
        foreach (wc_get_product($variation['variation_id'])->get_variation_attributes() as $attr) {
            echo '<pre>'; var_dump(wc_attribute_label( $attr )); echo '</pre>';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have looked into this a lot and could not actually find a proper solution. I tried this and it worked !

```
$variations = wc_get_product($product->ID);
$variation_title_pre =  $variations->get_formatted_name();
$vt = explode(" ",$variation_title_pre);
//var_dump($vt); see the exploded array
$variation_title = $vt[5].' '.$vt[6];
```

Answer (score 3):

To show the attributes name only in variations I have looked around a bit and the following seems to show the attributes name nicely:

```
$product_attributes = wc_get_formatted_variation( $v_product, true, false, false );
```

If you want to show variation with prices in loop and single page you can use the below snippet:

```
function woocommerce_single_item_custom() {
global $product;
$variation_ids = $product->get_children();
if( $variation_ids ) {
    foreach ( $variation_ids as $id ) {
        $v_product = wc_get_product($id);
        //Show only attribute name in variations title
        $product_attributes = wc_get_formatted_variation( $v_product, true, false, false );
        echo '<p class="variation_price">'. $product_attributes . ": ". wc_price( $v_product->get_price() ).'</p>';
    }
    }
}
```

Actions to override:

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_single_item_custom' );
  add_action( 'woocommerce_share', 'woocommerce_single_item_custom' );
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but in more recent Woocommerce you can simply use the Product variation class

```
$variation_product = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
$product_vari_name =  $variation_product->get_name();

echo $product_vari_name;
```

Comment: this included the parent product's name